# Find the next record by date for a person and compare it to their initial record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a moderate sized table (tbl) with:

```
id, 
person_id, 
date, 
resultA, 
resultB, 
resultC, 
resultD
```

with about 20000 results.

Each id of the table corresponds to a person's result in 4 different tests and their person_id.

e.g.

```
id 1 
person_id 2 (Joe Bloggs (made up name)) 
result on date (01/01/2012) 
A positive, 
B negative, 
C negative, 
D negative
```

I need to perform a query where it selects the records where one of the results was positive and the remainder negative. EASY!

```
SELECT id, person_id, date, resultA, resultB, resultC, resultD 
FROM tbl 
WHERE resultA = "P" AND resultB = "N" AND resultC = "N" AND resultD = "N"
```

The tricky bit is that I want to find out what the NEXT result for that person, **by date**, is for each of the records that meet the criteria above. I then want to compare the two results and see if the results have changed. i.e. resultB might change from "N" to "P" in the say, 1 month, between Joe Bloggs (made up name) results and I need to capture that.

I am sure I need to use subqueries in access 2010 but I can't quite work out how to do it.

Comment: FYI if you call a record with 20k records 'massive' you will get some funny looks...

Comment: Okay... it is a moderate size. It's just a lot for me when I'm used to dealing with a few hundred records :p

Comment: In databases, tables with hundreds of millions or billions of rows are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed date to a date, because date is a reserved word. This only returns an extra column for ResultA, but the subquery can be repeated for each result.

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.person_id,
       a.adate,
       a.resulta,
       a.resultb,
       a.resultc,
       a.resultd,
       (SELECT TOP 1 b.resulta
        FROM   tbl b
        WHERE  b.person_id = a.person_id
               AND b.adate > a.adate
        ORDER  BY b.adate, b.id) AS res
FROM   tbl AS a
WHERE  a.resulta = "P"
       AND a.resultb = "N" 
       AND a.resultc = "N" 
       AND a.resultd = "N"
```

I have edited `ORDER  BY b.adate` to include `b.id`, as per comments. Access returns matched records and if a person has more than one record on the same date, more than one record will be returned by Top 1.

Comment: Thank you - I get an error though: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: Also did you mean (SELECT TOP 1 b.resulta FROM tbl ** AS ** b...)

Comment: No, I did not mean `As b`, as is not required for table aliases. I tested the query before I posted. However, I notice that I have not put all the underscores back.

Comment: However, I still get this "At most one record can be returned by this subquery" - I Google'd it "•If the main query displays the result, the subquery must return a single value only. You get this error if it returns multiple values:
    At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

"

Comment: I don't quite know what it means.

Comment: Select top 1 returns one record. Perhaps your data is not as advertised or you have made changes to the query to suit your system?

Comment: Perhaps you should post real data (from a table), anonymized as necessary.

Comment: I have not meant to mis-advertise the data. I found out that when I changed ORDER by b.adate to ORDER by b.id it worked. There must be a few dates and person_id combinations that are duplicated - possibly two results on the same day?

Comment: You need the order by b.adate, but yes, you can add an id as well, say Order By b.adate, b.id. it is true that Access returns matches.

Comment: This is great. It is the springboard to do what I needed. Cheers for your help.